# PHP INSERT boolean values into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert boolean values into mysql table through PHP Script.

Here is my code:

```
$id = "104"
  $bool1 = true
  $bool2 = false

$sql = "INSERT INTO Monday  SET Id = '$id' , morning = '$bool1' , night = '$bool2' " ;

//Store the result in $result
$result = $conn->prepare($sql) ;

// Get the result  in a Returnvalue var
if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception($result->error);
}
$result->bind_param("sii" ,$patientId , $morning , $night );
$returnValue = $result ->execute();
return $returnValue ;`
```

In MYSQL table structure

```
morning and night both are of type BOOLEAN (tinyint(1))
```

When I execute this code true and false both inserts value '0' .

Comment: yes thats because your structure of column is tinyint 1 that means only one value can be inserted, change the column to varchar(4) and check again

Comment: what are the sample values for your `$bool1` and `$bool2`

Comment: The code does what you have made it to. So I wonder a bit what the actual question is. Saying that, interpolating the variables into the query-string directly often is error prone. That might but must not be the cause of your issue.

Comment: TinyInt(1) only knows 0(false) and 1(true). so instead of inserting true or false insert 0 and 1.

Comment: Show us a `var_dump($bool1);` and `var_dump($bool2);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly $bool1 and $bool2 has value true and false

Comment: @hungrykoala  $bool1 and $bool2 has value true and false

Comment: @Spurti is it done like this: `$bool1 = true` or `$bool1 = "true"`?

Comment: @hungrykoala $bool1 = true

Comment: That should set it to 1  or 0, Try doing this instead. `$bool1 = 1` for true and `0` for false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `morning` and `night` are tinyint you should pass numbers(integers) 0=false and 1=true.

Also your `mysqli_` code is a little odd, when using prepared parameterised queries you do not concatenate values into the query text, you use `?` parameters

```
$id = "104"
$bool1 = 1
$bool2 = 0

$sql = "INSERT INTO Monday  SET Id = ? , morning = ? , night = ?" ;

$result = $conn->prepare($sql) ;

// Get the result  in a Returnvalue var
if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception($result->error);
}
$result->bind_param("sii" ,$patientId , $morning , $night );
$returnValue = $result ->execute();
return $returnValue;
```

> You might also like to rethink your database design. Having a table for each day is very odd. Instead consider a table with a more generic name, and in it have a column called `dayname` or something like that.

So your table might look like this

```
id
dayname
morning
night
```

and a single table would hold all the days of the week

Comment: I did tried entering table name as a Variable but it failed."INSERT INTO '$dayOfWeek'  SET Id = ? , morning = ? , night = ?"

Comment: No thats not what I ment! You cannot use a parameter for a table name or a column name

Comment: Actually I have 7 tables Monday , Tuesday , Wednesday .... etc . All 7 tables structure is same. I want this one query to apply for all 7 tables. How can I make this query dynamic ? Shall I give  table name as variable $dayOfWeek which can have any value from Monday till Sunday.

Comment: No. Make ONE TABLE to hold all 7 days. That is what I have been trying to say

Comment: No I am not allowed to do so.

Comment: Then you can only do `$day = 'Monday'; $sql = "INSERT INTO $day  SET Id = ? , morning = ? , night = ?" ;`